# the smart way to recombine these two lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have the following lists in python which i want to recombine into a dictionary/list:

```
names = ['banana','grapefruit','apple']
colors = ['yellow','pink','green']
```

to

```
fruits = [
{'name':'banana','color':'yellow'}, 
{'name':'grapefruit','color':'pink'},
{'name':'apple','color':'green'}
]
```

what's the best way to do it? i'm currently tying my brain up in knots trying to write loops.

please help! :)

Comment: If i wanted to do this for n 'fruit attributes' eg. if fruit_attributes = ['name','color','taste',...], how would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: You should edit the question (if you can, can't find the reputation needed right now). Also, in what format are the values? `[[name1, name2], [color1, color2]]` or `[[name1, color1], [name2, color2]]` or something completely different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fruits = [{"name": name, "color": color} for name, color in zip(names, colors)]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[ {'name': name, 'color': color} for name, color in zip(names, colors) ]
```

The usual terms and conditions apply:

- In Python 2, itertools.izip is advisable for potentially large lists
- If the actual data has many lists/attributes, this can be generalized to be more elegant on the large scale
- Warranty void if seal is broken
- ...