# re-combining a list/dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079940/the-smart-way-to-recombine-these-two-lists-in-python/4079979#4079979)

i have the following lists in python which i want to recombine into a dictionary/list:

from

```
fromfruits = { "names" : ['banana','grapefruit','apple'] , "colors" : ['yellow','pink','green'], ... }
```

to

```
tofruits = [
{'name':'banana','color':'yellow',...}, 
{'name':'grapefruit','color':'pink',...},
{'name':'apple','color':'green',...}
]
```

what's the best way to do it **so that i can have n properties** listed in fromfruits?

please help! :)

Comment: The first bit of code isn't valid Python. Do you mean `fromfruits = {"names" : ["banana", "grapefruit",...], "colors" : [...], ... }`?

Comment: I think the question isn't clear enough. Do you want all color combinations for all names, or something else? [see different answers below]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the request is now to be more general:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> ff = {'colors': ['yellow', 'pink', 'green'], 'names': ['banana', 'grapefruit', 'apple'], 'blah': ['a','b','c']}

>>> [dict(izip(ff.iterkeys(), v)) for v in izip(*ff.itervalues())]
[{'blah': 'a', 'colors': 'yellow', 'names': 'banana'},
 {'blah': 'b', 'colors': 'pink', 'names': 'grapefruit'},
 {'blah': 'c', 'colors': 'green', 'names': 'apple'}]
```

since the order of `keys` and `values` are the same (assuming no intervening modifications to the dictionary).

Comment: I think the point of this question is not to mention the names ('colors', 'names') anymore but allow any unknown number of names. Else it'd be pretty much the same as his last question.

Comment: So the color is 'banana' and the name is 'yellow'? What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: @significance: if the answer is correct for your question, click the check mark box to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be pretty hard to go from keys like 'names' to 'name', teaching the program how to do proper english singlularization ... so i renamed the keys in the input:

```
ff = dict(name=['banana','grapefruit','apple'], color=['yellow','pink','green'], 
          yummy=[True,False,True])
```

You can solve this problem with `zip` again:

```
# make fruits [('yellow', True, 'banana'), ('pink', False, 'grapefruit'), ... ]
fruits = zip(*ff.itervalues())

# then add the names to each fruit
tofruits = [dict(zip(ff.iterkeys(),fruit)) for fruit in fruits]
# gives: [{'color': 'yellow', 'yummy': True, 'name': 'banana'}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[dict((x, fromfruits[x][n]) for x in fromfruits.keys())
  for n in range(len(next(fromfruits.itervalues())))]
```

Optimize as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> fromfruits
{'colors': ['yellow', 'pink', 'green'], 'names': ['banana', 'grapefruit', 'apple']}
>>> [{'name': name, 'color': color} for name in fromfruits['names'] for color in fromfruits['colors']]
[{'color': 'yellow', 'name': 'banana'}, {'color': 'pink', 'name': 'banana'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'banana'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'name': 'grapefruit'}, {'color': 'pink', 'name': 'grapefruit'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'grapefruit'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'name': 'apple'}, {'color': 'pink', 'name': 'apple'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'apple'}]
```

And now in some more detail (re-formatted for clarity):

```
>>>[{'name': name, 'color': color} 
        for name in fromfruits['names'] 
        for color in fromfruits['colors']]
```

This is a "list comprehension" with a double `for` which goes over all combinations of names and colors. You can add a third loop if you want to mix in other attributes, like "shape" or whatever.

Comment: I don't think bananas are supposed to be pink and green.

Comment: @Seth: I agree, but I take it as just a sample dataset that the OP thought of, not an attempt of biological warfare ;-)

Comment: I think the problem (as opposed to the previous question the OP linked to) is that the number of properties is variable - there may be more than just `name` and `color`. Also, he's not looking for a cartesian product of fruit names and colors, he's trying to remap the structure.

Comment: Right, but it's also not the result that the OP is looking for. He wants the items to be zipped, if I understand correctly.

Comment: This is a cross-product, not a transposition.

Comment: @Seth and @Ignacio: I understand the question differently, taking the `...` in the OP's code as a request for all properties for each name. I could be wrong, of course. Perhaps the question isn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

not very pythonic, but ...

```
keys = fromfruits.keys()
nvals = len(fromfruits[keys[0]])
tofruits = [ ]
for i in range(nvals):
    tofruits.append ({ })
    for k in keys:
        tofruits[-1][k] = fromfruits[k][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a bit more convoluted than the average list comprehension because of the nested dictionaries.

**However** if you can create the right iterable then a list comprehension is the way to go.

Try:

```
tofruits = [ {'name':n, 'color':c} for n,c in zip(fromfruits['names'], 
                                              fromfruits['colors']) ]
```

Here the `zip` function is used to produce tuples which match the correct `name` and `color`.  This is a good way to go here because both are stored in basic lists within the `fromfruits` dict.

These tuples (from `zip`) are then unpacked into `n` and `c`, which are then used as in a typical list comprehension.